# Tengo un proyecto de blazor wasm y en un método post obtengo 405 method not allowed

Tags: blazor

Mi proyecto blazor wasm tiene un método grabar que siempre obtiene el mensaje 405 method now allowed. Lo que no entiendo es porque no está permitido, si todo es una sola solución, se supone que el blazor wasm core hosted se crea desde una plantilla integrada, por lo que debería de estar todo bien. Sin embargo, al parecer solo a mi me ha pasado esto ya que no veo que el público pregunte sobre esto y las repuestas que hay no solucionan el problema.

El método get funciona sin problemas, es el post el que me trae problemas.

Lo que quiero saber es que estoy haciendo mal para que se pueda grabar. O es que blazor es una tecnología que no funciona aún, quizás esté a tiempo de cambiarme a otra que si funcione.

Luego de leer muchas respuestas que no corrigen mi problema encontré una que decía que configure CORS:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784715/blazor-and-webapi-in-same-solution-why-is-the-post-response-405-method-not-all

Pero esto tampoco funciona.

````
        public async Task<ActionResult<Personal>> PostPersonal([FromBody] Personal personal)
        {
          if (db.Personal == null)
          {
              return Problem("Entity set 'ProtegiaContext.Personal'  is null.");
          }
           
            db.Personal.Add(personal);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();           
           
            return personal; 
        }```

''' async Task Grabar()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage respuesta;
        if (ejecutivo.PersonalId == 0)
        {
             respuesta =  await http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/personal", ejecutivo);
        }
        else
        {
             respuesta = await http.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/personal/{ejecutivo.PersonalId}", ejecutivo);
        }
    }'''
````

Comment: Te puedo asegurar que la tecnología funciona bien. Falta mucha información para determinar porque te pasa lo que te pasa, pero lo pronto pon [HttpPost] arriba de la función en el controlador

Comment: Dependiendo de la versión de .net que estás usando debes modificar una serie de archivos. Sin embargo en las últimas versiones **Program.cs** es el archivo donde configuras **CORS** y los métodos permitidos **GET, PUT, etc…**. Agrega las versiones de .net que estes usando

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo que encontré. https://github.com/davElsanto/testAngularNetCore/blob/master/SolicitudesApiRest/Program.cs

Comment: Pero como te expliqué depende de la versión de .net que estes usando ese ejemplo de hace unos 8 meses atrás